# Cannot log in to new user

Tags: ubuntu, putty, login

I have created a user with "sudo adduser angela"  at the command line. I did not use useradd by mistake.

Then tried to log in, via a new putty session. This fails after I provide the password.

Diagnosis is hampered by my lack of knowledge and fail2ban (or something) cutting my IP off for 10 minutes after every 3rd failure! :(

Environment - Ubuntu server 14.04 LTS with all patches and updates. 
fail2ban is running.

The home directory exists and has the correct permissions and ownership.
When I am logged in I can become the new user with "su angela". 
I have "sudo usermod -a -G ssh angela" and restarted ssh.

Any help appreciated. 
Ian

p.s. Actually the account was create with useradd, deleted, the home directory removed, and then it was re-created with adduser. Doubt that makes any difference though.

Comment: Make sure password auth is allowed in sshd config or setup keys and try again.

Comment: To do this, look into `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` for the line `PasswordAuthentication yes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to edit  /etc/ssh/sshd_config, skip to the bottom and add the user's name to the AllowUsers line.

Then restart ssh.